# How can I select integers and array elements?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, alias

I am able to select repeated values in "col3" into an array and to arrange them by "col1", "col2" by using the following:

```
select "col1", "col2", array_agg("col3"  order by "col1", "col2") as myArray FROM 
     myTable group by "col1", "col2"
```

Next, I want to select the first two elements of the array (so they appear in their own columns) and to continue to arrange them "col1", "col2" by doing something like this:

```
select "col1", "col2", element[1], element[2] from 
    (select "col1", "col2", array_agg("col3"  order by "col1", "col2") as myArray FROM 
         myTable group by "col1", "col2") as  vv(element)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot subscript type integer because it is not an array
```

Is there a way to convert the integer values of "col1" and "col2" so I can place the array elements into separate columns organized by "col1" and "col2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table alias `vv(element)` is wrong because the inner query has 3 columns, not just one. By only specifying one column, you only rename the first one (`col1` to `element`)  and the other two columns keep their original names from the inner query.

So your alias needs to provide names for all three columns:

```
select "col1", "col2", element[1], element[2] 
from (
   select "col1", "col2", array_agg("col3"  order by "col1", "col2") as myArray 
   FROM myTable 
   group by "col1", "col2"
) as vv(co1, col2, element);
```

`vv(co1, col2, element)` essentially renames `myarray` to `element`.

As all your columns in the inner query have proper names, you don't really need the column aliases in the table alias:

```
select "col1", "col2", myarray[1] as element_one, myarray[2]  as element_two
from (
   select "col1", "col2", array_agg("col3"  order by "col1", "col2") as myArray 
   FROM myTable 
   group by "col1", "col2"
) as vv;
```